# how to interpret as streaming feature from arff format?

Tags: java, machine-learning, weka, feature-selection

I am trying to build an algorithm for streaming feature selection.

currently I dont have streaming data , so I am using UCI dataset (arff format) as streaming data. Streaming data means each attribute comes one by one.

So, I want to use data as one attribute and class. The following code read data and store in instance object.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\Exp\\iris.arff"));
Instances data = new Instances(reader);
reader.close();
data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes() - 1)
```

iris data has sepal length , sepal width, petal length, petal width attribute and class attribute.
I want to store sepal length and class attribute in another instance object.
HOw can I do this ?